# HTTP Server capable of proxying requests

Tags: apache, http, https, proxy

For performance reasons, I had to rewrite a part of our web infrastructure.

For this purpose, I have written the critical part as a web application in C++. This web app listens on a given port, accepts exactly one TCP connection at a time, and processes all HTTP requests it receives on the current connection.

You can start it like this to listen on port 8080:

```
./webapp 8080
```

While it works flawlessly and much faster than before, its limitation is the one-connection-at-a-time nature of the application. You cannot serve HTML pages, Javascript, and images simultaneously over more than one connection with just one instance of the application.

To overcome this limitation, I want to run a front-end, reverse-proxy HTTP server, which listens on port 80, and redirects incoming HTTP requests evenly on multiple instances of my web app running in the background. These instances could be created **at boot time** like this:

```
./webapp 10000
./webapp 10001
./webapp 10002
./webapp 10003
./webapp 10004
./webapp 10005
./webapp 10006
./webapp 10007
./webapp 10008
./webapp 10009
```

The frontend should be configured to establish a **permanent** HTTP connection to each web app **at start time**, and then forward incoming HTTP requests to one of the running web apps, spreading them evenly.

The reverse-proxy should also support SSL from the client to itself. Support of SPDY would be a plus, but is not a must.

My question is: Which HTTP reverse-proxies would be able to work as a frontend in my scenario? If you know more than one, which are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 0):

What are your motivation for having a single connection only server? It sounds like a terrible choice for a webserver. Each client browsers will typically send dozens of requests in parallel when your site shows up.

If you spawn a process by TCP connection, you'll end up having bad performances. Really, what you're looking for here is a multithreaded server instead of a multi-processes infrastructure (what is the point of having different processes?)

Still, there are several paths you can go down:

- You fork your `webapp` each time you receive a request if you really want to have separate processes. It will not be good performance-wise but it's the closest of your initial question I can think of.
- You stay with your single threaded `webapp` but you maintain a list of sockets you listen to, and you pair them with their "buddy socket" which are the ones they forward the traffic to (note that it works both ways). Still, this won't be optimal performance wise because you might be kernel-calls bound.
- You spawn a new thread for each request, and then treat this request in this thread only, as you do with your single threaded architecture.

If I were you, I would turn directly to Solution 3, because it is simply the best choice. It is not too much trouble since it stays close to your single thread approach (just a pair of sockets) and it doesn't have the performance hit of forking processes all over the place.

I don't think you will find a webserver that fits your needs, because it is not a standard way to handle such situations, and I doubt anybody took the time to develop it :)

**Edit:**

Ok, I understand your issue from your edit.

Still, for me, the problem to solve is still the same: you need a process that dispatches trafic to your processes. I do not think you will find such a dispatcher out of the box, and so you will need to implement it using one of the three techniques I mentioned.

If you think about it, you are really trying to implement one side of a proxy and the other side is the forwarding to your `webapp`. So you should use proxy techniques IMHO.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but in all honesty I don't even think you have read my question. The motivation for having a single connection server was that I don't want to re-invent the wheel. I only wanted to rewrite the performance critical part and leave connection pooling and such to a more mature, already existing web server. I DO NOT want to spawn a new process for every TCP connection. That's why I said I want to spawn my processes *at boot time* and that the frontend should be configured to establish a permanent HTTP connection to each web app at start time.

Comment: In essence, I'm looking for a good http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy (see the image on the right and the examples).

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't necessarily need a reverse proxy, but rather a load balancer. I'd set up [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) so that each webapp process counts as one backend and then do round-robin balancing so that every new connection goes to the next process in the list.

[Nginx](http://nginx.org/) can also do these things, but I'm not sure whether it comes with loadbalancing out of the box or if that is an additional module. The benefit of Nginx is that it can cache static assets such as CSS and images.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is a good option

Pros:

- Supports SSL termination
- Supports [load balancing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) out of the box
- [Upstream keepalive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive) connections
- Has SPDY support(no server push though). Latest version adds http2 support with spdy removed.

Cons:

- You will have to hardcode the upstream servers in your nginx configuration as below. There is no easy way to read upstream server settings through environment variables if you update them dynamically.

  ```
  http {
      upstream myapp1 {
          server localhost:10000;
          server localhost:10001;
          server localhost:10002;
      }
      server {
          listen 443 ssl spdy;

          location / {
              proxy_pass http://myapp1;
          }
      }
  }
  ```